# Can i use autoencoder for predicting time series missing data?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, autoencoders

I have time series data set of current and voltage at a regular interval of time there are some missing value . can i use autoencoder to predict the missing value?

Answer (score -1):

Intervention Detection can be used to predict/replace missing values. see http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html

A downvote probably motivated by a lack of understanding of outlier detection procedures motivated me to be somewhat more pedantic and to explain in detail with an example.

Consider data shown here where period 4 is known to be 1140.0 .

[image] . Now let's consider the case where the 4th value is missing and we want to estimate it for completeness sake. Let's change the 4th value from 1140 to 0.

[image] . We then use AUTOBOX which senses an unusual value of 0.0 at time period 4 and develops a useful model combining arima structure and latent deterministic structure.  Here is the model [image] .

A listing of the identified anomalies is here [image] where -1090 is the estimated coefficient at period 4 ...thus the replacement value is 0 - (-1090) or 1090 . Recall that the original true value was 1140.

The advantage of using Intervention Detection is that if there is stochastic memory in the data it can play a useful role in predicting the unknown/unrecorded values. Of course if there are large amounts of missing values there can be consequences.

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would like to comment that any procedure that attempts separate univariate imputations of voltage and current is likely to be inferior to one that imputes both values simultaneously, accounting for their possible lack of independence.  A truly responsive answer also would inquire *why* the data need to be imputed: what is the reason for missingness, what is the pattern of missingness, and how will the imputed values be used?

Comment: I totally agree that one should not use the suggested univariate method when one has a multi-series data set. Additionally the detection of pulses is a pre-cursor to asking why !. But before you can ask Why you need to detect the particular time point that is in question. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/31373941_Outliers_in_Multivariate_Time_Series discusses the multivariate extension

Comment: Missing values usually do not need to be detected--they are apparent in the data.  Regardless, if you need clarification to post a sensible answer to a question, then please use comments to ask the original poster.

Comment: agreed rectified is the goal as missing values are  obvious.